# QtQuick: Module is not installed

Tags: linux, windows, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm struggling with a custom QML module. The weird thing is that it works when I build and run perfectly fine on Linux (Ubuntu), but when I build and run on Windows, I get the following runtime error

> Module jbQuick.Charts is not installed.

My root project directory contains a folder `qml/jbQuick/Charts` which holds the `qmldir` and QML files. The QML directory is added in the `.pro` file:

`QML_IMPORT_PATH = qml`

The qml directory is added in the main.cpp file:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("jbQuick/Charts"));
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qml"));
```

In the QML file where I want to use the custom module I state:

```
import jbQuick.Charts 1.0
```

Am I missing something? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that relative path is interpreted differently on your Windows system - possibly, because the current directory when you run your program is not your project root directory. Could you try absolute path, i.e:

```
engine.addImportPath("<your-project-root>/qml");
```

If that works, you can use GetModuleFileName to create a correct path relative to binary, at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it!

Comment: also make sure that this path is absolute - I've spent couple of hours to figure out that qtcreator creates new directory for launching compiled app and **DOESN'T** copy my module (also jbQuick) there.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the `qml folder` to your `build folder` worked for me.